# Why is the htaccess in my subdomain folder overriding aspects of the htaccess in my main domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, mod-rewrite

Let me explain my setup here, I have two domains, for the sake of naming them lets call them domain1.com and domain2.com. I have shared hosting that runs cPanel.

Domain1.com is my main domain, and is what I have my hosting account setup using. I have a website hosted at that domain. Domain2.com is set as an add-on domain, and directs to a folder inside of the main domains root. That has it's own website (a Ghost blog).

That all works fine. However the websites hosted at the two domains are quite different and I did not want the subdomain to work, but as far as I can tell add-on domains in cPanel have to have a subdomain in order to be added to the account. The redirect options for the subdomains in cPanel aren't good enough for me, as I wanted anyone accessing say domain1.com/domain2 to get a 404 error as if it didn't exist. So I set up the .htaccess file for domain1.com to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#301 (permenant) redirects all HTTP requests to HTTPS (SSL)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#404 redirects all domain.com/subdomain requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/domain2/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
#404 redirects all subdomain.domain.com & www.subdomain.domain.com requests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.domain1.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.domain1.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
```

This worked perfectly, anyone tryting to access domain2 via domain1 would get a 404 error. But that was before I installed Ghost on domain2 After getting Ghost installed I created an .htaccess file in the domain2 folder inside of domain1's root.I had to put this in it in order for Ghost for to run, as it uses NodeJS:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:55555555/$1 [P,L]
```

This also works perfectly except for one aspect. Now all requests to the domain using domain1.com have started working again. For example if I type domain2.domain1.com it will now show me the Ghost blog where as before it was correctly displaying a 404 Not Found error. Why is this and how do I go about rectifying this issue?

As a side note, I also started trying to have all http requests redirect to https. I added the following to the domain1.com htaccess file as I wanted all requests on both domains to redirect to https and I assumed this was necessary:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Now this *kind of* works. All requests, whatever they are (with or without www for instance), redirect to https, and when I visit it in my browser I get a green the icon indicating it's secured with SSL. Again even with this the previous issue of the domain redirect still doesn't work. But I have another odd issue here.

If I type in my browser simply "domain1.com" (ie without https:// or www. or a combination of the two), it will show just "domain1.com" in the address bar but with the green icon and say it is secured. If however I type in "domain2.com" (again with no https:// or www etc.) it does the same thing **except** it states it is **not** secure, suggesting it requested http.

And yet if I type in www.domain2.com or http://domain2.com, that works and I get the secured icon. It is highly puzzling. It seems that the https redirect works on every request except for just "domain2.com" while any other variation (www.domain2.com, http://domain2.com etc) works fine. Any clues? I mean clearly I've done something wrong with the htaccess files but I don't know what, I got most of what I'd put in them from searching sites like Stackexchange, but personally I don't really know anything about them or how they work.

Comment: See [How directives are applied](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#how) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have fixed my own problem here.

I corrected the main htaccess so the https redirect acts like this;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

From what I can tell it's better to do it this way than the way I had it previously. This in itself didn't fix the problems. What fixed it for me is editing the domain2.com htaccess to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
#Force WWW if it isn't in the request
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
#Or include WWW even if it is in the request
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
#Then Force it to use https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#Defines this domain so main htaccess rules for subdomains work
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?domain2.com$ [NC]
#Proxy for Ghost
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:55555555/$1 [P,L]
```

Now everything works. All requests are redirected to https. All requests to the subdomain from the main domain fail with a 404. domain2.com now redirects to https://www.domain2.com *or* https://domain2.com so it is now always secured by SSL. I'm a novice at htaccess as is probably evident and I've no doubt some or all of this could have unnecessary elements removed or simplified so if anyone wants to correct my syntax so it's less messy I'd appreciate it.